# using an image with my existing submit button

Tags: html, ajax

I have this `button` that executes a `php` file using `ajax`, but it needs to use an image that has the path: `src="{ROOT_PATH}mchat/form.gif`" any help is appreciated thanks!

```
<form id="myform"  method="GET"  class="form_statusinput">
   <input type="hidden" name="toid" id="toid" value="{mchatrow.MCHAT_USERNAME}">
   <div id="button_block">
     <input type="submit" id="button" value="Enter">
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `image` type input:

```
<input type="image" src="submit.gif" alt="Submit">
```

You could insert PHP into the input that like this:

```
<input type="image" src="<?{ROOT_PATH}?>mchat/form.gif" alt="Submit">
```

Comment: Is it possible to do by not using css?

Comment: So change <input type="submit" id="button" value="Enter"> to <input type="image" src="<?{ROOT_PATH}?>/submit.gif" alt="Submit"> right?

Comment: YES, the image type still submits the form

Comment: Not a problem, please do so when its time :)

Comment: hey i added style="margin: 0; padding: 0; to <form id="myform"  method="POST"  class="form_statusinput" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;"> but it keeps breaking lines any idea on ho to fix it by using html and not css?

Comment: Not until I see a demo link